# when login from english store the website redirect to Arabic store

Tags: php, magento

> I have developed new website with English and Arabic language using
>   Magento CMS , what I had is when login from English store after
>   logging the website redirect to Arabic store , I checked the code and
>   I cannot find where the problem and why when logging from English
>   redirect to Arabic store .

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
}

/**
 * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
 */
protected function _loginPostRedirect()
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl()) {

        // Set default URL to redirect customer to
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
        // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
                Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
            )) {
                $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
                if ($referer) {
                    $referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
                    if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                    }
                }
            } else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
            }
        } else {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
        }
    } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
    } else {
        if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
        }
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's a Stack Exchange site for Magento questions, and even questions that could help lead you to an answer.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/redirect-user-after-login

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can this by [event observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) of magento.

Use event `customer_login` for  this redirection and using `setAfterAuthUrl` and this  will work when `customer is loggin` through `customer/account/loginPost`.

**config.xml code like:**

```
   <global>
<models>
  <magento29859026>
    <class>Stackoverflow_Magento29859026_Model</class>
  </magento29859026>
</models>
</global>
<frontend>
<events>
  <customer_login> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <customer_login_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>magento29859026/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>RedirToArabic</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
      </customer_login_handler>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
</events>
</frontend>
```

**Observer code look like:**

```
<?php 
class Stackoverflow_Magento29859026_Model_Observer
    public function RedirToArabic(){
        if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()=='customer_account_loginPost'):
            $arbicurl=Mage::getBaseUrl().'?___store=YOUR_STORE_CODE'
             $session->setAfterAuthUrl($arbicurl);  
        endif;
    }
}
```